# Finitely generated nilpotent group where every element is of finite order is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

> Let $G = \langle g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_m\rangle$ be a nilpotent group, where each $g_i$ has finite order.  Prove $G$ is finite.

I'd like to show this by showing that the lower central series has successive quotients that are finite, i.e.,

$$|\gamma_n(G) / \gamma_{n+1}(G)| < \infty$$

I'm going to show this by induction.  I'm on the base case

$$\gamma_1(G)/\gamma_2(G) = G/[G,G]$$

Any reason why this should be finite?  Any idea how I can argue that $\gamma_{n+1}(G) / \gamma_{n+2}(G)$ should be finite in the inductive step, assuming $\gamma_n(G) / \gamma_{n+1}(G)$ is finite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a nice problem because you don't use induction directly but prove it in several steps (only one of which requires induction):

**Step 1**: If $N\trianglelefteq G$ such that $[G,N]\le Z(G)$ and both $N$ and $G$ are generated by a finite number of elements of finite order, then $[G,N]$ is also generated by a finite number of elements of finite order.

(This can be proved by commutator arithmetic.)

**Step 2**: For $G$ as above, all elements of the lower central series are generated by finitely many elements of finite order.

(That's the part that requires induction, but is otherwise a trivial consequence of step 1.)

**Step 3**: An abelian group generated by a finite number of elements of finite order is finite.

(This is trivial as well.)

Putting the three steps together solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much @jpvee for your answer.  Could you please point me in the right direction in showing Step 1?  I'm sort of going in circles with commutator arithmetic.

Comment: Under the conditions of step 1, you have $[gg',nn']=[g,n][g,n'][g',n][g',n']$  for all $g,g'\in G$, $n,n'\in N$ (cf. e.g. identity #3 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator#Identities_.28group_theory.29). From this, it follows that $[G,N]$ is generated by the set of $[g_i,n_j]$ where $G=\langle g_1,\ldots,g_m\rangle$ and $N=\langle n_1,\ldots,n_k\rangle$. It also implies that $[g,n]^{o(n)}=1$ for $g\in G$, $n\in N$, so those generators of $[G,N]$ all have finite order.

Comment: OK, this makes sense.  And then in putting these three pieces together, this shows $\gamma_n(G) / \gamma_{n+1}(G)$, correct?

Comment: Yes, because in step 2 you show that $\gamma_n(G)$ is finitely generated by finite order elements, and of course the same is true for $\gamma_n(G)/\gamma_{n+1}(G)$ which is abelian, so step 3 tells you that that factor group is finite.

Answer (score 8):

Let $G$ be a nilpotent group of class $c$, finitely generated by torsion elements. Then $G/\gamma_2(G)$ is an abelian group, also finitely generated by torsion elements, hence it must be finite.

Consider $\overline{G}=G/\gamma_3(G)$. This is a nilpotent group (of class $\leq 2$, and again finitely generated by torsion elements) and hence $\gamma_2(\overline{G}) \subseteq \zeta(\overline{G})$. By the argument above, $\overline{G}/\gamma_2(\overline{G}) \cong G/\gamma_2(G)$ is finite. Hence $\overline{G}/\zeta(\overline{G})$ is finite.

At this point we need a lemma, mostly attributed to I. Schur; its proof relies on a simple application of the transfer map: if $X$ is a group and $X/\zeta(X)$ is finite, then $\gamma_2(X)$ is finite (see for example D.J.S. Robinson, *A Course in the Theory of Groups*, 10.1.4. [here][1]).

This yields $\gamma_2(\overline{G})$ is finite. But $\gamma_2(\overline{G}) \cong \gamma_2(G)/\gamma_3(G)$. It follows that $G/\gamma_3(G)$ is finite.

Continuing this argument to $\gamma_{c+1}(G)=1$, this shows that eventually $G$ is finite.

**Note** (added May 25th 2023) Another way to prove the statement is to apply *Dietzmann’s Lemma*: a finite subset of a group consisting of torsion elements and closed under conjugation  generates a finite subgroup. This result can be found in  the quoted book of Robinson.

[1]: https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/MATH676/D.J.S.%20Robinson%20A%20Course%20in%20the%20Theory%20of%20Groups.pdf

Comment: How does $G/\gamma_3(G)$ being finitely generated imply that $\gamma_2(G)/\gamma_3(G)$ is also finitely generated?

Comment: I am using the fact that a *subgroup of finite index of a finitely generated group is again finitely generated* (Schreier's Lemma, see for example https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Schreier%27s_lemma).

Comment: Why does $\gamma_2(G)/\gamma_3(G)$ have all elements of finite order?

Comment: @Mizar If $G$ has only elements of finite order, so does every subgroup and quotient and hence section.

Comment: But the assumption is that only the $g_i$'s have finite order (this doesn't guarantee all elements have finite order, right?)

Comment: @Mizar, thanks for pointing out a flaw in my previous proof. I updated the proof to a correct one.